# get row number of dragged row in tableview

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, drag-and-drop, tableview

i have two table views where you can drag a row from table A to table B.
this works fine.

but i need to know, which row number will dragged from table A.
This is my code of table A and the problem, too:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, writeRowsWith rowIndexes: IndexSet, to pboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
   pboard.declareTypes([NSStringPboardType],owner: nil)
   pboard.setString(persons[0].objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString, forType: NSStringPboardType)
        return true
}
```

at the moment i always dragged the first element of "persons" 
i need a solution where i can set a row number (or something like this) instead of the static "persons[0]".

is there an way for this?

Comment: How about `rowIndexes`?

Comment: yes i think that this is the right way, but i do not know, how i can use it. person[rowIndexes] doesn't work

Comment: okay, i have it: persons[rowIndexes.first]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `persons[rowindexes.first]` ?